# How to access string value from new class that inherit string type

Tags: python, oop, class

I want to define a new class that inherit the build in str type, and create a method that duplicates the string contents.

How do I get access to the string value assigned to the object of my new class ?

```
    class str_usr(str):
        def __new__(cls, arg):
            return str.__new__(cls, arg)
        def dub(self):
            # How to modify the string value in self ?
            self.<attr> = self.<attr> + self.<attr>
```

Thanks for any help :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in Python are immutable, so once you have one string, you can't change its value.  It's almost the same as if you had a class derived from `int`, and then you added a method to change the value of the `int`.

You can of course return a new value:

```
class str_usr(str):
    def dup(self):
        return self + self # or 2 * self

s = str_usr("hi")
print s # prints hi
print s.dup() # print hihi
```

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question. However, from both your and Mike Grahams answer, I can see that my idea was not a good general approach.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you want to inherit from `str` at all (which is prettymuch never useful anyhow). Make a new class and have one of its attributes be a string you access, that is

```
class MyString(object):
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string

    def dup(self):
        self.string *= 2
```

Also, note about this:

- Name your classes with `CamelCaseCapitalization` so people can recognize they are classes. `str` and some other builtins don't follow this, but everyone's user-defined classes do.
- You don't usually need to define `__new__`. Defining `__init__` will probably work. They way you've defined `__new__` isn't especially helpful.
- To add new functionality to strings, you probably don't want a class; you probably just want to define functions that take strings.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in Python you could just use the multiplication operator on string:

```
>>> s = "foo"
>>> s*2
'foofoo'
```

Comment: Ah, I just see that Alok already mentioned this... Well, I'll leave my answer anyway to emphasize that subclassing in this case is overengineering/obfuscation.

Comment: Your answer is good because it mentions that the OP doesn't probably need subclassing.  We don't know what he wants to do with his subclass, though.